# Why is this query failing?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select ssn from tab2 except select ssn from tab1;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select ssn from tab1' at

Comment: Have you tried reading the mysql manual? You have 5 questions with the exact same title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXCEPT` is not supported in `MySQL`

This article looks at the various ways in which you *can* do an anti semi join [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Answer (score 1):

To do an "except" you could...

```
select ssn from tab2 where ssn not in ( select ssn from tab1 )
```

Comment: Assuming of course that `tab1` does not have any `NULL` values for `ssn`